# Sort Array with multiple items

Tags: ios, arrays, nsarray

I am looking to sort an array and manipulate it. The array comes from a scraped XML file on the server and is the following:

```
{
    award = Varies;
    deadline = "3/1";
    description = "To be considered for many Northeastern scholarships, you must apply for admission, submit a high school transcript, and complete the necessary scholarship applications NO LATER than March 1st prior to your anticipated fall enrollment. Additional scholarships requiring a separate application, portfolio, personal interview, or tryout are also available.";
    gpa = "2.50";
    grade = "12TH Undergraduate";
    link = "http://www.njc.edu/Scholarships/";
    location = Colorado;
    title = "Northeastern Junior College Scholarships";
},
    {
    award = "$1,000";
    deadline = "3/1";
    description = "Must be a resident of the State of Colorado and a citizen of the United States. Criteria for selection include: a short written essay on the Mayflower on the topic listed in the application, GPA and class rank, ACT or SAT scores, evidence of honors received, activities in and outside of high school, employment and leadership, a letter of recommendation.";
    gpa = "0.00";
    grade = 12TH;
    link = "http://www.coloradomayflowersociety.org/scholarship.htm";
    location = Colorado;
    title = "Colorado Mayflower Society: Scholarship";
},
```

I am looking to 1) sort certain items in the array by looking if an element (for example grade) contains "undergraduate" and remove all objects that contain that string in grade. I have been looking for this for a while but can only find help when there is one item in an array, not multiple.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you have an array of two items and you want to remove the first item because grade has the string "undergraduate" in it?

Comment: you are talking of filtering, not sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways... for example (for mutable array):

```
NSIndexSet *removeIndexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return obj[@"grade"] && [(NSString *)obj[@"grade"] rangeOfString:@"Undergraduate"].location != NSNotFound;
}];
if (removeIndexes.count) {
    [array removeObjectsAtIndexes:removeIndexes];
}
```

**EDIT:** If you need to check all values:

```
NSIndexSet *removeIndexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSUInteger index = [[(NSDictionary *)obj allValues] indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [(NSString *)obj rangeOfString:@"Undergraduate"].location != NSNotFound;
    }];
    return index != NSNotFound;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter to split the array into two arrays. One for graduates and another for undergraduates. Then use sort to sort them. Like this

```
    var undergraduates = array.filter({$0.grade.rangeOfString("Undergraduate") != nil})
    undergraduates.sort({$0.grade <= $1.grade})

    var graduates = array.filter({$0.grade.rangeOfString("Undergraduate") == nil})
    graduates.sort({$0.grade <= $1.grade})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a predicate for filtering

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"grade": @"12th"}, @{@"grade": @"12th Undergrade"}];
array = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT grade LIKE %@", @"*Undergrade"]];
```

or

```
array = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT grade CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"Undergrade"]];
```

or predicate with block

```
array = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [[evaluatedObject valueForKey:@"grade"] rangeOfString:@"Undergrade"].location == NSNotFound;
}]];
```

---

NSArray also offers filtering by indexes

```
NSArray *filteredWithIndexSet = ({
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [[obj valueForKey:@"grade"] rangeOfString:@"Undergrade"].location == NSNotFound;
    }];
    [array objectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
});
```

<sup>Note: this example uses the statement expression syntax.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

If these objects in the array are `NSDictionary`s then you can loop through the array and implement some simple logic to get the items you want.

```
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:array.count];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    if (![dict[@"grade"] containsString:@"Undergraduate") {
        [filteredArray addObject:dict];
    }
}
```